# Почему не отрабатывает ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Таблица с данными из бд:

```
 <tr>
 <td><div class="alert <?=$colorClass?>" role="alert"><p><?=$users['id']?></div></td>
 <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?=$users['id']?>">
 <td><div class="alert <?=$colorClass?>" role="alert"><p><?=htmlspecialchars($users['delivery_adress'], ENT_QUOTES)?></p></div></td>
 <td><div class="alert <?=$colorClass?>" role="alert"><p><?=htmlspecialchars($users['delivery_time'], ENT_QUOTES)?></p></div></td>
 <td><div class="alert <?=$colorClass?>" role="alert"><p><?=htmlspecialchars($users['surname'], ENT_QUOTES)?> <?=htmlspecialchars($users['name'], ENT_QUOTES)?> <?=htmlspecialchars($users['second_name'], ENT_QUOTES)?></p></div></td>
 <td><div class="alert <?=$colorClass?>" role="alert"><p><?=htmlspecialchars($users['sum'], ENT_QUOTES)?></p></div></td>
 <td><button type="button" name="delivery_status" value="1" class="btn btn-xs btn-success mb-3" id="delivered">Отдал</button></td>
 <td><button type="button" name="delivery_status" value="2" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger mb-3">Отказ</button></td>
 <td><button type="button" name="delivery_status" value="3" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning mb-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Перенос</button></td>
 </tr>
```

dost.php, который обрабатывает её:

```
<?php

require_once('db.php');

if(!empty($_POST['delivery_status']))
{
    $form_id = (int) $_POST['form_id'];
    $status = (int) $_POST['delivery_status'];
    $SQL = "UPDATE Users SET delivery_status='$status' WHERE id='$form_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);
}
?>
```

AJAX, который я написал, и который почему-то не отрабатывает, т.е. в бд не сохраняются данные, полученные от кнопки, а просто загружается пустая страница с dost.php.

```
$('button[name="delivery_status"]').on('click', function() {
    let $btn = $(this);
    let id = $btn.closest('tr').find('input[name="form_id"]').val(); // получаем id
    // формируем данные
    let data = {
        form_data: id,
        delivery_status: $btn.val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dost.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Данные сохранены");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Попробовал file_put_contents("test.txt", $_POST['form_id']);  - там сохраняются корректные значения id.
Вардамп пост-запроса выглядит следующим образом, т.е. не передаются value кнопок.
array(2) { ["form_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["delivered"]=> string(0) "" } 
В консоли никаких ошибок, php отдаёт 200, только это: [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript.
SQL-запрос корректный, т.е. на чистом php с перезагрузкой страницы отрабатывает корректно.
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
Нужно чтобы в зависимости от нажатой кнопки заносились 1, 2 или 3 в delivery_status, привязанную к id.

Comment: попробуйте $_REQUEST['delivery_status']

Comment: @Vfvtnjd и что это даст?

Comment: delivery_status: $btn.attr('value') должно быть, когда заполняете let data